# How can I do Hough Transform in OpenCV and C#?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing

Regarding this [Opencv Tutorial](http://funvision.blogspot.com/2016/01/hough-lines-and-canny-edge-sobel.html), the following C++ code snippet:

```
vector<Vec4i> lines;
           // Find hough lines 
    HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 100, 100, 10);

           // Prepare blank mat with same sizes as image
    Mat Blank(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));

       // Draw lines into image and Blank images
        for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
         {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];

        line(image, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 0), 2, CV_AA);

         line(Blank, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2, CV_AA);

         }
```

has been translated into C# like this:

```
private void openFileDialogButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        const string filename = @"E:\___MSc in Computer Systems & Network\EMSC1,2,3\lena.png";

        Mat image = Cv2.ImRead(filename, LoadMode.GrayScale);

        Mat edges = new Mat();

        Cv2.Canny(image, edges, 95, 100);

        Cv2.ImWrite("edges.jpg", edges);

        Mat dx = new Mat();
        Mat dy = new Mat();

        Cv2.Sobel(edges, dx, MatType.CV_32F, 1, 0);
        Cv2.Sobel(edges, dy, MatType.CV_32F, 0, 1);

        Cv2.ImWrite("dx.jpg", dx);
        Cv2.ImWrite("dy.jpg", dy);

        Mat linesssssss = new Mat();

        Cv.HoughLines2((CvArr)linesssssss.ToIplImage(),
            (CvMat)edges,
            HoughLinesMethod.Standard,
            1,
            Math.PI / 180,
            100, 100, 10);
        //Cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, 100, 100, 10);

        List<Vec4i> lines = IntPtrToList(linesssssss.Data);

        Mat Blank = new Mat(image.Rows, image.Cols, MatType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            Vec4i l = lines[i];

            Cv2.Line(image, new OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Point(l[0], l[1]), new OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Point(l[2], l[3]), new Scalar(0, 0, 0), 2, Cv.AA);

            Cv2.Line(Blank, new OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Point(l[0], l[1]), new OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Point(l[2], l[3]), new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2, Cv.AA);

        }

        //Cv2.ImWrite("houg.jpg", image);
        //Cv2.ImShow("Edges", image);
        //Cv2.ImWrite("houg2.jpg", Blank);
        //Cv2.ImShow("Edges Structure", Blank);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems to be not working. It is giving the following exception:

```
Nonpositive cols or rows
```

This is the original image from the article:

[image]

Comment: Did you look at what the error actually says?

Comment: @theB, differs in the number of arguments. I have tried various combinations of arguments and data types. None of them actually works. The code I posted, is actually showing least error.

Comment: Sorry couldn't read that tiny text. With a magnifier I can tell you that it's telling you that lines is supposed to be a `CvArr`, and edges is supposed to be a `CvMat`.

Comment: https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/master/sample/SamplesCS/Samples/HoughLinesSample.cs

Comment: suggestions for improving this question: 
--- When asking for debugging help always include the full exception with name and stacktrace, not just ex.Message
--- Mark the line where the exception happens with a comment
--- Remove all lines after the exception and al lines that are not required for the exception, until you have a minimal code example
--- Break up the line where the excpetion happens into as many sub-commands as possible, i.e. `Cv.HoughLines2((CvArr)linesssssss.ToIplImage()` --> `CvArr l2 = CvArrr)linesssssss.ToIplImage(); Cv.HoughLines2(l2,...`

Comment: ... --- Don't just start with a link without a description, write why the reader should follow the link, and how it relates to your question. 
--- Explain how the c++ code in your first code block relates to your problem, right now it seem totally redundant.
--- If the jpg files that your program reads and writes are relevant to your problem, include them in the question. If they are not relevant, remove the lines that write them from the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Github's [sample code](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_samples/blob/f9b1b7594564900ca55ce435f15ba179e8f833c8/SamplesCore/Samples/HoughLinesSample.cs) for `HoughLinesP`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filename = "Alliance.jpg";

        Mat imageIn = Cv2.ImRead(filename, ImreadModes.GrayScale).Resize(new Size(800, 600));
        Mat edges = new Mat();

        Cv2.Canny(imageIn, edges, 95, 100);

        //HoughLinesP
        LineSegmentPoint[] segHoughP = Cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, Math.PI / 180, 100, 100, 10);
        
        Mat imageOutP = imageIn.EmptyClone();

        foreach (LineSegmentPoint s in segHoughP)
            imageOutP.Line(s.P1, s.P2, Scalar.White, 1, LineTypes.AntiAlias, 0);

        using (new Window("Edges", WindowMode.AutoSize, edges))
        using (new Window("HoughLinesP", WindowMode.AutoSize, imageOutP))
        {
            Window.WaitKey(0);
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]